# Doing pre-checks before calling controller in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, struts

I recently started working on a spring MVC project which uses spring security.

I had to do some pre-checks before user's request gets to the controller.

This is what I want to achieve, like I have worked a lot in struts and in struts we can extend all the action classes to a superclass let's say `BaseAction` and then write some validation here so that they gets called before calling  the sub class methods.

I would like to achieve same thing here but don't know how to start.

I cannot use filters as i need to make database calls and web-service calls in pre checks.

I just need the pointers .

Comment: disclaimer: no idea who this dude is, not my blog, just the first google hit: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was missing the term (interceptor) to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement an interceptor using [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html).

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

Configuring the applicationContext in XML.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="my.package.MyInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

The interceptor.

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public boolean preHandle(
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {

        // your logic
        return true;
    }
}
```

> **Returns** true if the execution chain should proceed with the next interceptor or the handler itself. Else, DispatcherServlet assumes that this interceptor has already dealt with the response itself.